# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException tomcat error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

My log of error on eclipse

```
Dec 07, 2013 12:52:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\ROOT\QMSa.war
Dec 07, 2013 12:52:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/QMSa]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [uploadServlet] and [FileUploadDBServlet.FileUploadDBServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/uploadServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2450)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2132)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2086)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

Dec 07, 2013 12:52:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\ROOT\QMSa.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/QMSa]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I deployed my WAR file in the webapps folder.
And on eclipse I got this error.

I am using the same version of JRE for tomcat and eclipse.
Also this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
hello
  </description>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>FileUploadDBServlet.FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/uploadServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

from the index.html page I send a form.The action for the form is given by

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="question_form" action="uploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
```

please provide help

**UPDATE**

```
@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)    // upload file's size up to 16MB
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // database connection settings
    private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elect";
    private String dbUser = "root";
    private String dbPass = "root";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets values of text fields
```

Comment: It seems you are also using annotation for your servlet class. Can you share the code of your servlet?

Comment: just posting part of the code.

Comment: @frostjogla the package and .java file is the same

Comment: @JunedAhsan it started working as soon as I removed the annotations

Comment: Moving the comment to answers sections as it was the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are also using annotation for your servlet class, which is causing the conflict/confusion for the web container.